# Should I worry about closed form solutions in research?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operations-research

I am an MSc student studying operations research (specifically bioinvasions) and it seems that a lot of the mathematics in this area focuses quite heavily on PDE's, Optimal Control Theory, and Algorithms/Numerical methods in order to solve the bioeconomic models. Most of this math I don't understand at the moment, but I think that I would have the capacity to learn them once I got into the theory. Now, I haven't taken a course on ODE's or PDE's in quite a while and from what I remember in the classes, we focused quite a lot on closed form solutions and solving various classifications of equations by hand.

What I am concerned about is that I have lost the ability to be able to fluently generate these closed form solutions by hand and what impact this would have on my own research. Is it detrimental that I might not be able to do partial fractions, for example. So, I suppose I am curious how often higher level math in applied research is dependent on the ability to solve equations by hand in closed form or if I should put more of my attention towards algorithms and computational (I mean computational in a coding sense) solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The techniques that you studied in an introductory course in differential equations are all easily automated- tools like Mathematica and Maple can do these computations much more reliably than you could ever do them.  You should make use of such tools when appropriate, but you should also make an effort to learn more about the underlying analysis of differential equations and about various numerical methods for solving equations.

Comment: I think this is helpful. I suppose the balance comes with knowing when it is appropriate to use a tool and understanding the principles that make the tool effective for the job at hand. I'll keep this in mind going forward, thank you.

Comment: @Brian, I think that people that can't solve easy ODE's and PDE's can't use Mathematica or Maple well.  I think they make a lot of mistakes and don't recognize their mistakes when using those pieces of software.  I could easily be wrong.  Have you met some people that are using those tools effectively despite not being able to solve simple ODEs and PDEs by Hand?  I imagine that most engineers forget how to do them by hand.

Comment: My experience is that it is best not to “drill and kill” but rather to do some hand calculations and then relatively quickly move on to using tools like these so that students can deal with (what I consider to be) more important issues of modeling and analysis.  My experience is that very few students today have the patience to develop skill (e.g have a better than 80% chance of solving a problem correctly).

Comment: @BrianBorchers    Interesting!   I have not been teaching for the last few years.  My students still did everything with pencil and paper, but they did start using WolframAlpha to check their integrals.

Answer (score 2):

I am an applied mathematician and I have been applying PDE's, Optimal Control Theory, Finite Element Analysis, and Numerical Analysis to engineering problems and financial analysis for the past 25 years.

IMHO, you need to be able to solve by hand the simpler ODEs and PDEs to understand what is going on in more complicated problems.  Specifically, I think you need to be able to solve initial value problems of the following forms:

1. $y'(t) = f(y(t))$ where $t, y(t)$, and $f(y(t),t)$ are real and $f$ is a polynomial,
2. $a y''(t) + b y'(t) + c y(t) = f(t)$ where $a,b,c,t$ and $y(t)$ are reals and $f(t)$ is a polynomial, trigonometric, or exponential function,
3. $y'(t) = A y(t)$ where $A$ is a real valued matrix and $y(t)$ is a real vector, and $t$ is real, and
4. $a u_{xx} + b u_{yy} = c$ where $a, b, c, x, y$, and $u(x,y)$ are real and the value of $u$ is given on the boundary of a rectangular region.

Being able to solve these problems by hand will enable you to understand solutions provided by numerical methods.

I also found that understanding projections in $\mathbb R^n$ (and Hilbert Spaces) was useful for learning optimal control theory.  (A real matrix $M$ is called a projection matrix if $M=M^T$ (symmetric) and $M^2=M$ (idempotent).)

Answer (score 1):

I had a mid-career crisis about this 2 years ago, when I realised that I was expending brains and time to come up with closed-form solutions to save on computer runs. With compute becoming cheaper and cheaper, this didn’t seem to be a winning formula.

But see [Borwein & Crandall (2013)](https://www.ams.org/notices/201301/rnoti-p50.pdf). And for bioeconomics, is there a premium for algorithms that can run quickly on limited compute?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is useful to be able to identify situations where you are likely to obtain a closed form solution, even if you are not fluent in the process of obtaining the solution itself. I will not try to estimate the probability of coming across a pde/ode for which you can get the exact solution in closed form.